# How to check if menu item contains a word using twig

Tags: drupal, menu, twig, drupal-8

in the menu.html.twig theme template, I want to check if a menu item title contains a specific word.

so I tried this codes, but none of them worked.

```
{% elseif menu_level == 1 and 'separator' in item.title %}
{% elseif menu_level == 1 and 'separator' in item.title.raw %}
{% elseif menu_level == 1 and 'separator' in item.title|render %}
```

and I have the items: 'separator 1', ' separator 2', 'separator'

but couldn't solve the problem!

Comment: Please verify your variables as it should work. [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/lnwrlc)

Comment: i don't think item.title is just a variable, it seems to be like a drupal class

Comment: That doesn't matter at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.title` will give raw text, and the code to check is:

```
{% if 'separator' in item.title %}
```

You should check:

1. menu_level is 1 for your case. For my case, its coming zero (0)
2. check expected spelling/case of string 'separator'

You can print these variables for debugging purpose.

```
{{ item.title }}
{{ menu_level }}
```